# Is it possible to see what processes are using a USB device on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, usb, drivers

First of all, **I NOT talking about flash drives**. I have two devices connected to a USB3.0 hub. One of them is a HID device, and the other one is an imaging device. The second device doesn't show up as a camera (I don't even know how to access it) because it is handled by a proprietary software. All I know about it is that it is a UVC camera and it uses the `usbvideo.sys` driver.

I am trying to reverse engineer the software that came with this device, but the problem is that there are about 6 different processes on my computer that make the device work. I would like to narrow it down to one exe/dll file by checking which process is communicating with the USB devices (either the HID or the camera) or or one of their drivers.

Is this possible on Windows?

Comment: You are aware of the fact that usbvideo.sys is a Microsoft driver?

Comment: https://www.imatest.com/2017/01/how-to-determine-what-processes-are-using-a-device/

Comment: @Moab Thank you, I think you solved it. I didn't know that process explorer was capable of doing this.

Comment: @Ramhound Yes, the device is technically a camera, and it uses the UVC protocol, so of course it uses the built in video driver. But it's not a consumer webcam so there is some proprietary stuff on top of that. That's what I'm trying to reverse engineer.